# vhdl parser in C

Tags: c, parsing, vhdl

My question this time is about a c parser that will read vhdl code from a txt. To be honest, this is not exactly a question, but mostly a request to direct me to a link that will offer a short example. The assignment feels a little too heavy for me at this point and I am looking for something that will help me get things straight. I searched, but the topics I found either use dead links, or are not what I am looking for.

As I am a beginner to vhdl (not that it matters I guess in this case) and unfortunately to C as well, I am looking for a simple example that shows how the topology of a digital circuit is created. Even if it has only 2 gates, I think a short example will help me understand how it works.

My intention is to start reading from the txt file and create a list that stores each gate and its input/output in struct instances, but is still a little confusing in my mind and I don't where to start. If you know of an example that is posted somewhere, or any other simple example of a vhdl parser in C which I missed, please let me know where to find it; I will be immensely grateful.

I apologize for the nature of the topic (not a question), but I am just looking for a way to get unstuck.

Cheers

Comment: If you were really going to try this (writing a compiler is definitely “non-trivial”), I'd start with *Compilers: Principles and Techniques* by Aho, & al. (“The Dragon Book”) and probably the Gnu Bison manual. Along with some kind of good introduction to C (preferably updated to at least the C90 standard) and the VHDL specification. … at a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing languages like VHDL is a nontrivial exercise.

You aren't going to do it with strings, regexes and hacking and some simple bit of logic.     You need a basic compiler course to tell you how language processors read source code and interpret the symbols for meaning.

The circuit topology created is essentially a graph; you need to understand how to build a graph out of dynamically allocated nodes and how to link the graph elements using pointers, if you using the language C.

Do you actually need this level of knowledge? Most VHDL designers don't have this background, I don't think.

Then you need some background on how a VHDL front end with an syntax tree and a symbol table might assemble an actual circuit model of the circuit from this information.  Attribute grammars are probably helpful here, if you understand them; otherwise one has a complex walk over the AST to collect hints about circuit elements, and following linkages from symbols to determine connections.  The details of this for full VHDL are going to be pretty complex.

EDIT: It seems OP really wants to build a representation of a circuit; diving into a real compiler will likely confuse him since he seems to be inexperienced.

*What he really needs is a class in data structures, and then it would be relatively obvious how do do this*. [If you are going to work with complex software, this a must]. In the absence of that, building a C library to achieve the desired effect will probably teach him what he needs to know, and improve his C skills.

What the library needs are two types of operations:

a) For each node type N for N = and_gate, or_gate, RS_flop, clocked_flop, design a corresponding struct, and create a library member that will create that node type [call malloc with sizeof(struct...)].  For brownie points create a node  of type , create a "gate" called "wire".  It is a good idea
to make the node types very similar in content to allow other library procedures to manipulate most node types without having deep knowledge of what they are.  One way to do this is to make all node types use the same struct, with one struct slot containing  number representing N, and the other containing an array to represent the ports of a node; define a mapping of the array slots to named ports of the node type by convention.  For a D-flop, array[0] is the D input array[1] is the clock input, array[2] is Q,  array[3] is Q*, etc.   This is not an array of integers; rather it is an array of slots that can hold links to other nodes.  [Hint the array slots should let one build a circular list with an arbitrary number of elements].

b) Add an extra procedure call "LinkNodePorts", given 4 arguments: pointer to first node, first node port number, pointer to 2nd node, second node port number.  If your array slots can contain circular lists, this should be straightfoward to implement.

The act of "building a circuit topology" then reduces to a series of calls on the library to create the needed nodes, and link the ports together.
[You can imagine a VHDL compiler likely doing this, using your library].
Its your decision as to whether you want to link gate ports to other gate ports, or insist that gate ports always connect to a wire and vice-versa.

To provide the "example" that OP wants, consider:

```
      // library:
      struct node { int type; // use an enum to make this readable
                    (struct node)* ports[10]; // enough for most complex gate
                  }

      // library calls to construct RS flop from cross-couple NAND gates:
      struct node *nand_gate1;
      struct node *nand_gate2;
      // make the gates to implement an RS flop:
      nand_gate1= gate_library_make_nand_gate();
      nand_gate2= gate_libray_make_nand_gate();
      // connect gate outputs to other gate inputs:
      gate_library_connect_ports(nand_gate1,0,nand_gate2,1);
      gate_library_connect_ports(nand_gate2,0,nand_gate1,1);
```

That's it.  Library details left to the reader.

Comment: So, not an answer to not a question? Too long for a comment.

Comment: This assignment was given not in a c or vhdl, but on a course about simulation. Not sure if and where it will be useful, but the text will have a string in the form of - AND(A,B,X),OR(C,D,Y),XOR(X,C,Z),OR(Y,B,W),AND(Z,W,O)

Comment: A correction to my previous post. I meant "...the txt will have a string...".
 
I assume I have to simulate the structure of the circuit by creating the connections between the nodes with the use of a list of structs. Quite confusing for me with my current knowledge, which is why I asked for a link to something that will help, or even a simple c parser of vhdl. Anything you can offer at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are not a proficient X programmer for language X (in  your case, X==="C"), and I gave you a compiler for VHDL implemented in X, you will not be able to understand it.  In fact, you'll get lost in the sheer scale of the thing.  This is not the route to the understanding you seek. You do have the right idea; it is about connecting nodes represented as structs using pointers, etc.   That intutitive understanding should be enough to *use* VHDL compilers in practice, so it isn't clear to me why you want *more*.  Why is it that *you* want to construct such data structures yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment. I don't think you're being asked to write a "VHDL parser".

Your input is

```
AND(A,B,X),OR(C,D,Y),XOR(X,C,Z),OR(Y,B,W),AND(Z,W,O)
```

which is just an arbitrary list of gates in no language. You're probably being asked to turn this into VHDL, which is a bit pointless. Start by drawing a diagram of the 5 gates with connections to make sure you understand the connections. Scan the text above in C code, create five 3-input gate instances (which you're calling structs) for each gate, with connections, to give a C representation of your diagram.

Now write everything out as a VHDL structural description (an entiry and an architecture, where the architecture contains 5 gate instantiations, with connecting signals). You can find these all over the internet; start [here](http://www.gmvhdl.com/connect.htm).